# running java applications in docker with jboss or tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, jboss, docker

I have installed docker in my windows machine and run an image for java installation following instructions from "https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/dockerfile/java/" it allows me to run java commands as expected. But lets say I have a Java application which needs to be run on Jboss or tomcat. How do I create an image for this and how to add my application war file to deploy in server. As I have not much knowledge about creating docker file. It will be really very helful if you can tell how this can be done , so that I can run my application anywhere with Jboss/tomcat server using docker.

Answer (score 9):

Create a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM dockerfile/java

# Install Tomcat
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tomcat7

# Add your webapp file into your docker image into Tomcat's webapps directory
# Your webapp file must be at the same location as your Dockerfile
ADD mywebapp.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/

# Expose TCP port 8080
EXPOSE 8080

# Start Tomcat server
# The last line (the CMD command) is used to make a fake always-running
# command (the tail command); thus, the Docker container will keep running.
CMD sudo service tomcat7 start && tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
```

Build the image:

```
$ docker build -t tomcat7-test <Dockerfile's path>
```

And then, run it:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 tomcat7-test
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, sorry for taking so long as I was on vacation. I have tried installing tomcat using above Dockerfile. But after building and starting the container, it suddenly stops tomcat server. dont know whats going wrong. have tried it several times :( can u pls tell what could be the cause?
thankyou so much again!

Comment: Hi yashu, sorry for my late answer... What is the content of your catalina log file (/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out)?

Comment: Hello @FabienBalageas
How is the webapp.war created?

Answer (score 1):

Run this:

```
sudo apt-get -y install tomcat7
```

Make sure to add the `-y` before `install`.

Comment: alright, thank you;) but Why do I have to add "-y" though?